# wearable that provides raw sensor data export

Tags: running, walking

I would like to export raw accelerometer (and possibly other sensor) data from a wearable device (i.e. not just processed data such as number of steps and velocity, but x/y/z acceleration data and possibly others).
Thought this would be technically easy, but failed to find a suitable device so far when searching the internet and writing to manufacturers' customer support (so far, no or negative answers).
Does someone have experience with that and can possibly name a model from which this is possible?

Purpose is to monitor fitness and physical fatigue in disabled people with certain movement disorder diseases, where we are interested e.g. how "economical" they walk, not just how much, since motivation becomes a problem once every step becomes more and more difficult. For an academic project, we are looking for free (open) solutions that do not rely on expensive extra fees or contracts/goodwill of a company in addition to buying the devices.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about data extraction, not using the device in a fitness regimen.

Comment: I am open for suggestions where else to post it better. Thought that a solution would be best found with people enthusiastic for and familiar with these devices (and other programmers rather using mobile phones etc.).

Comment: I'd just look at the most popular wearables and see who (such as garmin) have api's and what you can access with them.

Comment: @JohnP: (a) In "What topics can I ask about here?", it reads "gear and gadgets used during exercise", and I do not suppose we want to limit the definition of fitness and exercise to healthy people; I added sth. about the purpose in the Question. (b) API: Yes, I did that. As written in the question, so far I could not find a device that offers what I need. In the case of Garmin, as far as I understand there is no free/open access to the accelerometer data, although they sell a kinmd of access for commercial work (which will There are APIsand SDKs,